# Console Window does not appear using Dev C++

Tags: dev-c++

When I compile and run my code, the console window no longer shows up.

(I have **"system("pause");"** included, this is not the issue).

I was trying to debug a program in **Dev C++** and must have changed some settings.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Dev-C++ is really old and the debugger is full of bugs. If you're sure the problem isn't with your code, then I'm assuming you've tried the basics, like restarting Dev-C++ and restarting the computer?

If that doesn't work, try reinstalling Dev-C++... It only takes a couple seconds to install it.

You can also try stepping the code.

Comment: If all else fails, you can check out [orwelldevcpp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/), if that's not what you're using. You didn't specify a version.

Comment: Yeah, use orwelldevcpp, the other versions are very outdated. orwelldevcpp looks just like dev cpp.

Comment: Thanks guys!  I am now using orwelldevcpp and it is working just fine.

Comment: No problem. If it helped you, please make sure to mark this answer as helpful so other people can use it.